# Angular custom FormControl with updateOn blur

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have a reactive form group that is working just fine with updateOn ***submit*** and updateOn ***change***.

But when I switch to updateOn ***blur***, the required error is triggered directly after entering a character in my custom form control and never goes away. Also, when I submit my form, all the values of my custom form controls are empty (even though the fiels are completed).

**My form TS:**

```
activityForm = this.fb.group({
    placeName: ['', { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(75)] }],
    description: ['', { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(25), Validators.maxLength(2000)] }],
  }, { updateOn: 'blur' })
```

**My form HTML:**

```
<form class="container" [formGroup]="activityForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="container__field">
        <p class="container__title">{{'poi.place_name' | transloco}}</p>
        <custom-input formControlName="placeName" placeholder="{{'poi.select_place_name' | transloco}}" [error]="activityForm.get('placeName')?.errors !== null && activityForm.get('placeName')!.touched"></custom-input>
        <custom-error [text]="'error.required' | transloco" *ngIf="activityForm.get('placeName')?.hasError('required') && activityForm.get('placeName')?.touched"></custom-error>
        <custom-error [text]="'error.maxlength' | transloco : { charact : this.activityForm.get('placeName')?.errors?.maxlength.requiredLength }" *ngIf="activityForm.get('placeName')?.hasError('maxlength')"></custom-error>
    </div>

    <div class="container__field">
        <p class="container__title">{{'poi.description' | transloco}}</p>
        <custom-textarea formControlName="description" placeholder="{{'poi.select_description' | transloco}}" [limit]="2000" [error]="activityForm.get('description')?.errors !== null && activityForm.get('description')!.touched"></custom-textarea>
        <custom-error [text]="'error.required' | transloco" *ngIf="activityForm.get('description')?.hasError('required') && activityForm.get('description')?.touched"></custom-error>
        <custom-error [text]="'error.maxlength' | transloco : { charact : this.activityForm.get('description')?.errors?.maxlength.requiredLength }" *ngIf="activityForm.get('description')?.hasError('maxlength')"></custom-error>
        <custom-error [text]="'error.minlength' | transloco : { charact : this.activityForm.get('description')?.errors?.minlength.requiredLength }" *ngIf="activityForm.get('description')?.hasError('minlength')"></custom-error>
    </div>

    <div class="container__button">
        <custom-button text="{{'poi.next_step' | transloco}}" color="primary" type="submit"></custom-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Custom FormControl TS (the textarea one):**

```
export class CustomTextareaComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() placeholder = '' // give a transloco string directly
  @Input() limit = 500
  @Input() error: boolean = false

  value: string | null = null
  currentNumberOfCharacters: number = 0
  isActive: boolean | undefined

  onChange: any = () => { }
  onTouch: any = () => { }
  touched = false
  disabled = false
  
  changes(event: Event) {
    if (this.disabled) return
    this.markAsTouched()
    this.value = event?.target ? (event?.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value : ''
    this.currentNumberOfCharacters = this.value.length
    this.onChange(this.value)
  }


  /* Methods needed by ControlValueAccessor to transform this component into a "form friendly" component */

  registerOnChange(providedFunction: any) {
    this.onChange = providedFunction
  }

  registerOnTouched(providedFunction: any) {
    this.onTouch = providedFunction
  }

  writeValue(providedValue: any) {
    if (providedValue) {
      this.value = providedValue
      this.currentNumberOfCharacters = providedValue.length
    }
  }

  setDisabledState(providedDisabledVal: any) {
    this.disabled = providedDisabledVal
  }

  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouch()
      this.touched = true
    }
  }

}
```

**Custom FormControl HTML (the textarea one):**

```
<div class="plnd-textarea">
    <div class="plnd-textarea__field-container" [class.plnd-textarea__field-container--written]="value" [class.plnd-textarea__field-container--active]="isActive" [class.plnd-textarea__field-container--error]="error">
        <textarea [placeholder]="placeholder | transloco" [value]="value" (keyup)="changes($event)" (focus)="isActive=true" (focusout)="isActive=false" [maxLength]="limit" class="plnd-textarea__field"></textarea>
    </div>
    <p class="plnd-textarea__characters">{{ currentNumberOfCharacters }}/{{ limit }} {{ 'common.characters' | transloco }}</p>
</div>
```

So my question is: How do I make updateOn ***blur*** work with a custom FormControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually missing the blur event. Also seems that there is a lot of noise in your code, don't know what for example `active` is for. Here is a cleaned up version:

Template:

```
<textarea [value]="value" (blur)="onBlur()" (keyup)="changes($event)"></textarea>
```

and TS:

```
value: string | null = null;
onChange: any = () => {};
onTouch: any = () => {};
disabled = false;

changes(event: Event) {
  if (this.disabled) return;
  this.value = event?.target
  ? (event?.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value
  : '';
  this.onChange(this.value);
}

onBlur() {
  this.onTouch();
}
registerOnChange(providedFunction: any) {
  this.onChange = providedFunction;
}

registerOnTouched(providedFunction: any) {
  this.onTouch = providedFunction;
}

writeValue(providedValue: any) {
  this.value = providedValue;
}

setDisabledState(providedDisabledVal: any) {
  this.disabled = providedDisabledVal;
}
```

Also you need to remove `markAsTouched()` from your onChange function, since otherwise your error will show immediately when typing, as the field becomes touched and as you have update on blur, means that the value does not change until blur event happens.

Here is a **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-utmym3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)** for your reference

Also you can look into the following article to not [reinvent the wheel when implementing ControlValueAccessor](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-a0ed4ad0fafd)

Comment: Ok I understand. And let's say I have a custom dropzone form control (using  this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dropzone), the (blur) attribute would still work ? @AT82

Comment: Never have used that, but looking at the documentation, it seems that there is only change event.

Comment: So it means that on more complex custom from controls (than just input/textarea), I can't use the (blur) attribute and thus the updateOn blur for this form control ? @AT82

Comment: define *more complex custom form controls*? If you are using libraries, it basically depends on the library and what kind of support they have for reactive forms, so it is completely up what the libraries provide.

Comment: For example a custom form control (let's say for example a multiselect) that is built only using some <div> (so no input nor textarea) @AT82

Comment: You can decide what events are available to the pieces you use in your 'Component'.  Of those, you can stitch together what you think means on Blur( ) .  Clearly the Blur events of any embedded inputs, but maybe also other stuff.   If there is no way for you to make an onBlur, then yes, you have to go with SUBMIT or CHANGE