# angular custom form control not calling onChange

Tags: angular, typescript, custom-component, angular-formbuilder

I am building a simple custom form control that requests data and populates a mat-select.
I have followed the angular tutorial and also several others...
These are my 2 favorite
https://sreyaj.dev/custom-form-controls-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

The dropdown is being populated.
So the service is fine. I can post that if you need it.

The initial value is pushed into the control using writeValue() so I believe the ContolValueAccessor is working.

The formGroup is setup to validate onBlur()

The registerOnChange is getting called.

If I select a new option from the dropdown, the event fires and I can see that data.Value has the new selected option.
I call onChanged and onTouched, but neither seem to affect the formGroup.

I can not seem to spot what I am doing wrong, or failing to do??

The other fields (name, description, etc) do cause the changed() event. So I believe the subscription to myFormGroup.changed  is working.

The question is  :  **Why is onListChange() not causing the formGroup to emit a changed() event in the parent component. **

Here  is the custom component

```
import { Component, SimpleChanges,Input, OnInit, forwardRef, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of  } from 'rxjs';
import { tap , switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { COA_Header } from '../COA_Header';
import { COA_Account } from '../COA_Account';
import { ChartOfAccoutsService } from '../services/chart-of-accouts.service';


const  VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CoaDropdownComponent),
  multi: true,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-coa-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './coa-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./coa-dropdown.component.css'], 
  providers:[
    VALUE_ACCESSOR
  ]
})
export class CoaDropdownComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  
  @Input() myprojectId : number; 
  @Input() includeBlankOption : boolean = true;
  value : string ; 

  data$ : Observable<COA_Account[]>;
  touched : boolean = false;
  disabled : boolean = false; 
  constructor(private coaService : ChartOfAccoutsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  
    this.data$ = this.coaService.getCOAByProjectId(this.myprojectId).pipe(
         switchMap((data : COA_Header) =>{
          let l : COA_Account[] = data.Accounts;  //return just the array of accounts


          return of(l);
        })
       
    );
    
  }



onListChange( data){
  console.log('coa item selected', data, this.touched); //this fires as expected
  this.value = data.value;
  this.markAsTouched();
  this.onChanged (data.value);
}

//these are pointers to functions that will be passed to us by FG
  onChanged : Function;
  onTouched : Function;
  
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
       console.log('rc called');  // this is happening
      this.onChanged = fn;
  }
  
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  
  writeValue(value_: string): void {
    console.log('fg set value',value_); //this gets called as expected
    this.value = value_;
     
  }

  markAsTouched() {
      if (!this.touched) {
        this.onTouched();
        this.touched = true;
      }
  }
  
  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
  }

  itemSelected(value_ : string){
    this.markAsTouched();
    this.value = value_;
    this.onChanged(value_);
  }

 
}
```

Here is the component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf ="data$| async as data">

    
    <mat-select appearance="fill" 
            style="background-color: white;border-radius:3px;padding:4px;"
            value="{{value}}"
            (selectionChange)="onListChange($event)"
            >
        <ng-container *ngIf = "includeBlankOption">
            <mat-option value="">---</mat-option>    
        </ng-container>
        <mat-option    *ngFor="let acct of data" [value]="acct.Name">[{{acct.AccountType}}] {{acct.Name}}</mat-option>
        
    </mat-select>
        
     
</ng-container>
```

Here is the parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit , AfterViewInit
        , Input, Output, SimpleChanges 
        , ElementRef, EventEmitter, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AbstractControl  , FormBuilder, FormGroup   
         , Validators
         , RequiredValidator, MaxLengthValidator, MinLengthValidator
  } from '@angular/forms';
import { IMyDpOptions, IMyDateModel, IMyDate, MyDatePicker } from 'mydatepicker';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { Observable,forkJoin, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilKeyChanged, pluck
  , switchMap ,tap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {CashFlow2 } from '../cash-flow2'
import {cashFlowService } from '../services/cash-flow.service';
import { sbList} from '../../list-management/sbList';
import { ListManagementService } from '../../list-management/list-management.service';
import { userDefinedSetting } from '../../udsForm/user-defined-setting';
 import {ListDropDownComponent } from '../../list-management/list-drop-down/list-drop-down.component'
import { UdsFormComponent } from 'src/app/udsForm/uds-form/uds-form.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cashflow-detail',
  templateUrl: './cashflow-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cashflow-detail.component.css']
})
export class CashflowDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  

    
   myFormGroup: FormGroup;
  myItem : CashFlow2;  
  
  public vm$ : Observable<any>;
    private myData$ : Observable<any>;  //combines proj and pRev in one observable
  
 

  public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    
    todayBtnTxt: 'Today',
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    firstDayOfWeek: 'su',
    sunHighlight: true,
    satHighlight: true,
    inline: false,
    height: '25px' 
  }; 
  
    
  // }
  
   
  
        constructor(private myFormBuilder: FormBuilder 
          , private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
          , private iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry 
          , private cashFlowService : cashFlowService
          , private listService : ListManagementService
           ) {
 
        }
        
        
        ngOnInit(): void {
          this.buildForm();
         
              
      

            this.myData$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
              pluck('id')
              //, tap(data => console.log('cf id', data))
              ,switchMap(itemId => this.cashFlowService.getItemById(itemId).pipe(
                    map(cf => {
                      //console.log('cf retrieved',cf);
                      this.myFormGroup.patchValue(<CashFlow2>cf );
                      this.myItem = cf;
                      return cf; 
                    })
                )
              )
            );

      } //end ngOnInit
  
 
      
      buildForm( ) {
        this.myFormGroup = this.myFormBuilder.group(
            this.myFormGroupDefinition()
            ,{ updateOn: "blur" }
        );


        this.myFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            this.saveMainForm();
           
             
        });

    }  //end buildForm



    //build the form based on a cashflow
    myFormGroupDefinition() {
            
            
      return {
          id :['' ,
                {
                validators:[ Validators.required]
              } 
            ],
            COA:['Mortgage'],   //this is the coaDropdown component
          clientId :['' ,
                {
                validators:[ Validators.required]
              } 
            ], 
    
          Name :['' ,
                {
                validators:[ Validators.required]
              } 
            ], 
       
          }
    }//end myFormGroupDefinition

    get f(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
      return this.myFormGroup.controls.get(key);
    }

    saveMainForm(){
          if(null == this.myItem){
            console.log('init form, no change needed');
            return;
          }

          const mergedItem : CashFlow2 = {...this.myItem, ...this.myFormGroup.value};
          //console.log('form values spread into myItem', mergedItem);
          this.myItem = mergedItem;
          this.saveToService(this.myItem);

    }

    

    saveToService(itemToSave_ : CashFlow2){
            let obs = new Observable<CashFlow2>();
            obs = this.cashFlowService.saveItem(itemToSave_);
            obs.subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.myItem = data;
                    this.itemUpdated.emit(this.myItem);
                     
        
                });
    }


}
```

here is the parent HTML

```
<ng-template #loading>
    <div   >loading...</div>
</ng-template>  
   

  <div *ngIf ="myData$ | async   as allMyData ; else loading ">

    <div  class="formgrid"   [formGroup]="myFormGroup"  > 

      
          <label class="fieldLabel" for="Name">coa :</label>
          <app-coa-dropdown
          class="formValue"
          myprojectId="3137"
          formControlName="COA"
          value="Mortgage"
          required></app-coa-dropdown>
          <span class="fieldErrorMessage" >coa message</span>

          <label class="fieldLabel" for="Name">Name :</label>
          <input class="fieldValue" type="text"
          formControlName="Name"
          name="Name"
          placeholder="Name"
          />
          <span class="fieldErrorMessage" >{{f['Name'].errors! |json}}</span>
          
      
         
        

        <input  class="fieldValue" type="text"
              formControlName="Description"
              name="Description"
              placeholder="Description"
              />
        <label class="fieldLabel" for="Description">Description :</label>
        <span class="fieldErrorMessage" >{{f['Description'].errors! |json}}</span>

        
    </div>

 
   
                
    <div  class="formgrid"   [formGroup]="myFormGroup"  > 
      
                <label class="fieldLabel">Save</label>
                
                <span class="actionButton"
                matTooltip="Save item"
                (click)="saveItem()"
                >
                <button [disabled]="!myFormGroup.valid">
                  <i class="material-icons md-24 ">save</i>
                </button>
              </span>
              <span class="fieldErrorMessage"></span>
              
              
              <label class="fieldLabel">Delete</label>
        
                   <span class="actionButton"
                        matTooltip="Delete this item"
                        (click)="deleteItem()"
                        >
                        <i class="material-icons md-24 ">delete</i>
                      </span>
                      <span class="fieldErrorMessage"></span>
                  
        
                    </div>
                     
 </div> <!-- end ngIf-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I always forget you can actually step into angular code ....

form.js has this...

```
function setUpViewChangePipeline(control, dir) {
    dir.valueAccessor.registerOnChange(function (newValue) {
        control._pendingValue = newValue;
        control._pendingChange = true;
        control._pendingDirty = true;
        if (control.updateOn === 'change')
            updateControl(control, dir);
    });
}
```

my whole form is set up to trigger on blur.
when I set the COA form element to updateOn:'change' then i do get it to fire correctly.

To make blur work, i need to capture the  matSelect onBlur and call onTouche

this question has also been addressed here...
[Angular custom FormControl with updateOn blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178531/angular-custom-formcontrol-with-updateon-blur)

excerpt from childcomponent.ts

```
onBlur(data){
  console.log('in blur')
  this.onTouched();
  console.log('exit blur');
}
```

excerpt from childcomponent.html

```
  <mat-select appearance="fill" 
            style="background-color: white;border-radius:3px;padding:4px;"
            value="{{value}}"
            (selectionChange)="onListChange($event)"
            (blur)="onBlur($event)"
            >
```